# How to update this animated view for iOS 15

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a "message bubble" that "springs" in from one side of the screen. I use the following code:

```
struct MessageView: View, Identifiable {
  let id = UUID()
  var side: MessageBubbleSide = .left
  let innerView: AnyView
  var hasBackground = true

  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      innerView
        .padding(.horizontal, .five)
        .padding(.vertical, .four)
        .messageBubble(
          displayFrom: side,
          hasBackground: hasBackground
        )
      Spacer()
    }
    .transition(.move(edge: side == .left ? .leading : .trailing))
    .animation(.spring()) 
  }
}
```

This works, but when building for iOS 15, it says `'animation' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: Use withAnimation or animation(_:value:) instead.`. I usually know how to do this in other circumstances, but haven't been able to solve it when wanting a spring animation as the view appears on screen. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

All I did was use the newer API which wants a value, where I just threw in a UUID:

```swift
.animation(.linear, value: UUID())
```

Comment: This has the same effect as the other comment, it doesn't actually animate when I add that

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a value which activates animation (aka, dependency). As you animate transition dependent on `side`, then it should be

```
.transition(.move(edge: side == .left ? .leading : .trailing))
.animation(.spring(), value: side)     // << here !!
```

Comment: `side` isn't a `@State` though, it's just assigned on init. So when I do this, it doesn't actually animate in. It just 'appears'

Answer (score 0):

If you want your animation to start when view appears use onAppear:

```swift
struct MessageView: View, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var side: MessageBubbleSide = .left
    let innerView: AnyView
    var hasBackground = true
    
    @State private var showHeadline: Bool = false // declare here
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            innerView
                .padding(.horizontal, .five)
                .padding(.vertical, .four)
                .messageBubble(
                    displayFrom: side,
                    hasBackground: hasBackground
                )
            Spacer()
        }
        .transition(.move(edge: side == .left ? .leading : .trailing))
        .animation(.spring(), value: UUID())
        .onAppear(perform: {
            self.showHeadline.toggle()
        })
    }
}
```